# .htaccess need to redirect direct calls to newdoamin and rest to index.php?var

Tags: .htaccess

I just moved my old site to a new URL but still using the old one to hosting files and other few stuffs. I want to redirect user to `http://newdomain.com` if the URL is `http://olddomain.com` but if the user insert something like `http://olddomain.com/abcd` it should go to the index file with abcd as parameters. Please help me out in this.

Comment: or instead of index can redirect to any other file say processvariable.php?abcd

Comment: can your code handle the redirect? ie redirect everything to index.php? and if query string is blank, your php script issues the 301?   would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and then in your php code, you would just do something like:

```
  <?php  
     if (!isset($_REQUEST['q'])){
         header('Location: http://newserver');
         exit();
     }
   ?>
```

you can remove the `!-d` and `!-f` if you don't want to check for existing files